# JNI code ie executed concurrently with garbage collection.

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, java-native-interface

It is written on the http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.com/2015/12/safepoints.html

> A Java thread is at a safepoint while executing JNI code. Before
>   crossing the native call boundary the stack is left in a consistent
>   state before handing off to the native code. This means that the
>   thread can still run while at a safepoint.

How is it possible? After all, I can pass a object's reference to `JNI`. 
In JNI I can set a field in that object.

It is clear that it can't be collected (we have a local reference). But, it can moved to old generation by a GC during full gc collection. 
So, we have the following situation:

```
GC collector:                          | Thread executing JNI code
compact old generation                 | modify object fields that can be 
and move object from young generation  | moved now! A catastrophe. 
to old generation.                     |
```

How JVM deals with that?

Comment: The `jobject`s in your native code are indirect references. The actual indirection mechanism may vary between different JVMs, and a JVM that uses a compacting GC will have to implement an indirection mechanism that allows for objects to be moved.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Nobody said you can't execute a setter in JNI, and nobody said that a `jobject` parameter can't be moved to another generation during a JNI call, and, specifically, nobody said that a `jobject` points *directly* at a Java object in memory,

Comment: When you use a JVM method to access the object, it ensure this is still safe even if you are running the GC.  Most likely this will stop the thread in JNI almost immediately if you have a STW collection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost every JNI call has a safepoint guard. Whenever you invoke a JNI function from a native method, a thread switches from `in_native` to `in_vm` state. A part of this transition is a safepoint check.

See [ThreadStateTransition::transition_from_native()](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/80d32985a3eb/src/share/vm/runtime/interfaceSupport.hpp#l220) which calls [JavaThread::check_safepoint_and_suspend_for_native_trans(thread)](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/80d32985a3eb/src/share/vm/runtime/thread.cpp#l2353)

```
// Slow path when the native==>VM/Java barriers detect a safepoint is in
// progress or when _suspend_flags is non-zero.
// Current thread needs to self-suspend if there is a suspend request and/or
// block if a safepoint is in progress.
```

That is, a thread calling JNI function while GC is active will be suspended until GC completes.